# What is the newline character for Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, office-automation, export-to-pdf

I'm using Adobe document generation API to create a PDF from Microsoft Word (.docx) template. I want to format the text that will replace the placeholders in the template with a paragraph or line break.

I've tried adding "\n" to the text but it didn't work

Comment: The standard line break under windows is the combination or \r\n (CR + LF). Bu this is not the same as a Paragraph! And then there is the hard line break..

Comment: What code have you tried so far?